# How to make async calls in prepare method of createSlice of redux-toolkit?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following `createSlice` method. I looked into the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) of `createSlice` where they have given an option to use the `prepare` method to customize the action creation.

I'm trying to make an API call, However the reducer is triggered before the API response. Hence my `action.payload` remains `undefined`.

Can `prepare` be used to make async calls ?

PS: I did not want to maintain my customized action creators in a separate function/file. The purpose of using `createSlice` is to improve code maintainability.

```js
export const authReducers = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: { ...initialState },
    reducers: {
        loginToConsole: {
            reducer: (state, action) => {
                console.log("Reducer Called", action);
                state.isLoggedIn = !state.isLoggedIn;
            },
            prepare: async (credentials) => {
                let response = await axios.post(
                    `${apiEndPoint}/api/auth/login`,
                    credentials
                );

                console.log(response);
                return { payload: { ...response.data } };
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot. `prepare` is called synchronously.

You should use thunks for that - see [This Chapter of the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)

That said, nothing prevents you from writing your thunks just in the same file. Many people do that.